# Cannot see Python function documentation in R with reticulate

Tags: python, r, documentation, reticulate

I'm running into an issue on RStudio (1.4) where I cannot see Python documentation in the Help Panel. I'm using `reticulate` v. 1.20 and my Python interpreter is working fine. But if I use the F1 keyboard shortcut or run e.g., `?np.random.rand` I get the following error:

```
>>> ?np.random.rand
Error in html$page(pydoc$describe(resolved), html$document(resolved, name)) : 
  attempt to apply non-function
Error in html$page(pydoc$describe(resolved), html$document(resolved, name)) : 
  attempt to apply non-function
Error in html$page(pydoc$describe(resolved), html$document(resolved, name)) : 
  attempt to apply non-function
```

The Help panel reads: /python/np.random.rand.html not found

Haven't seen this issue anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be fixed in the development version of `reticulate` which can be installed as follows:

`devtools::install_github("rstudio/reticulate")`

Answer (score 0):

Does that feature exist with `reticulate`? There is an in-built function to request help: `py_help` - https://rdrr.io/github/rstudio/reticulate/man/py_help.html
e.g. the following boots up a help file for me

```
library(reticulate)
os <- import("os")
py_help(os$listdir)
```

Comment: Documentation for `reticulate` describes using F1 to display help https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/rstudio_ide.html

Comment: Ah my mistake I only spotted the `?np.random.rand` part sorry. You might get further posting this on their Github page if no one can help you here

Comment: Thanks, there's an issue there addressing this https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/1011. Fixed it by installing the development version: `devtools::install_github("rstudio/reticulate")`

Comment: Sounds like this comment should be posted as an answer @WillHipson?  I just ran into the same issue and the dev version (1.20) also resolved it for me.